# How do you round decimal in Matlab without the extra zeros?

Tags: matlab

for example Pi?

3.1416

When I use `round(pi,2)` the output is 3.1400 but I want it to be 3.14 without the extra zeros. Then I used `sprintf('%.2f',pi)` and the output was '3.14' but I want it without the quotation marks.

Is there a command that will just give me **3.14**?

Comment: Do you want to display that value, or compute with it? To display, use `fprintf` rather than `sprintf`.

Comment: what you see in the *Command Window* depends on the [format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) that is specified. E.g. by typing `format long` you will see more decimal points...The numbers are of `double` type anyway, so you won't reduce the size there with `rounding`. For printing follow Cris's advice

Comment: thanks you guys, 

the only problem I have now is 

fprint('%.2f' , pi) 

the output is 
3.14 >> 

is that fine?

Comment: Use `fprint('%.2f\n' , pi)`. You need to explicitly output a newline character if you want subsequent output to come on a new line.

Comment: or if it's just for the console display, you can try typing `format bank`, that will truncate all the numbers displayed to 2 decimals.